# Ubuntu VM on Virtualbox (windows 10 host) freezing

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 on Virtualbox in a Windows 10 host OS.

Every now and then the OS freezes and I am unable to click or do anything.
It also happens that sometimes my session gets destroyed and gdm restarts asking me to login again, and after that still I can't click or type anything. Cannot find any gdm related log.

- Virtualbox version: **6.1.38**
- Host OS: **Windows 10**
- Guest OS: **Ubuntu 22.04 LTS**  (upgraded from 20.04, and the same problem was happening with 20.04)
- Kernel: **5.15.0-50-generic**
- Virtualbox guest additions: **6.1.38**

This is the log entry when this occurs:

```
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: rcu:         3-...!: (1 ticks this GP) idle=3f9/1/0x4000000000000000 softirq=22352/22352 fqs=0
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:         (t=28263 jiffies g=31689 q=2761)
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: rcu: rcu_sched kthread timer wakeup didn't happen for 28262 jiffies! g31689 f0x0 RCU_GP_WAIT_FQS(5) ->state=0x402
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: rcu:         Possible timer handling issue on cpu=0 timer-softirq=6406
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: rcu: rcu_sched kthread starved for 28263 jiffies! g31689 f0x0 RCU_GP_WAIT_FQS(5) ->state=0x402 ->cpu=0
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: rcu:         Unless rcu_sched kthread gets sufficient CPU time, OOM is now expected behavior.
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: rcu: RCU grace-period kthread stack dump:
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: task:rcu_sched       state:I stack:    0 pid:   14 ppid:     2 flags:0x00004000
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: Call Trace:
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  <TASK>
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  __schedule+0x23d/0x5a0
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  schedule+0x4e/0xc0
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  schedule_timeout+0x87/0x140
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  ? __bpf_trace_tick_stop+0x20/0x20
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  rcu_gp_fqs_loop+0xe5/0x330
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  rcu_gp_kthread+0xa7/0x130
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  ? rcu_gp_init+0x5f0/0x5f0
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  kthread+0x127/0x150
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  ? set_kthread_struct+0x50/0x50
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x30
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  </TASK>
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: rcu: Stack dump where RCU GP kthread last ran:
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: Sending NMI from CPU 3 to CPUs 0:
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: NMI backtrace for cpu 0
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: CPU: 0 PID: 2143 Comm: portainer Tainted: G           OE     5.15.0-50-generic #56-Ubuntu
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: Hardware name: innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox, BIOS VirtualBox 12/01/2006
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: RIP: 0033:0x445f74
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: Code: 19 c0 89 f9 41 ba 01 00 00 00 41 d3 e2 45 21 c2 49 63 c1 0f 1f 00 48 39 c3 76 35 48 8d 04 86 41 f7 d2 f0 44 21 10 48 8b 42 08 <48> 89 05 75 8e 1a 02 b8 ff ff ff ff 48 8d 0d 71 8e 1a 02 f0 0f c1
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffdcad91140 EFLAGS: 00010206
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: RAX: 000000c000048800 RBX: 0000000000000001 RCX: 0000000000000000
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: RDX: 000000c000046000 RSI: 000000c000042008 RDI: 0000000000000000
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: RBP: 00007ffdcad91150 R08: 00000000ffffffff R09: 0000000000000000
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: R10: 00000000fffffffe R11: 00007ffdcadd8090 R12: 00007ffdcad91140
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: R13: 00000000000001b6 R14: 04fefa1a22742c08 R15: 0000000000000001
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: FS:  00000000025ef8b0 GS:  0000000000000000
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: NMI backtrace for cpu 3
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: CPU: 3 PID: 773 Comm: udisksd Tainted: G           OE     5.15.0-50-generic #56-Ubuntu
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: Hardware name: innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox, BIOS VirtualBox 12/01/2006
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: Call Trace:
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  <IRQ>
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  show_stack+0x52/0x5c
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  dump_stack_lvl+0x4a/0x63
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  dump_stack+0x10/0x16
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  nmi_cpu_backtrace.cold+0x4d/0x93
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  ? lapic_can_unplug_cpu+0x90/0x90
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  nmi_trigger_cpumask_backtrace+0xec/0x100
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  arch_trigger_cpumask_backtrace+0x19/0x20
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  trigger_single_cpu_backtrace+0x44/0x4f
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  rcu_dump_cpu_stacks+0x102/0x149
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  print_cpu_stall.cold+0x2f/0xe2
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  check_cpu_stall+0x109/0x270
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  rcu_sched_clock_irq+0x9a/0x250
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  update_process_times+0x94/0xd0
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  ? tick_nohz_handler+0xb0/0xb0
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  tick_sched_handle+0x29/0x70
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  ? tick_nohz_handler+0xb0/0xb0
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  tick_sched_timer+0x8c/0xc0
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  __hrtimer_run_queues+0x106/0x210
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  ? kvm_clock_get_cycles+0x11/0x20
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  hrtimer_interrupt+0x101/0x220
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  __sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x5e/0xe0
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x7b/0x90
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  </IRQ>
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  <TASK>
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  asm_sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x1a/0x20
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: RIP: 0010:_raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x25/0x30
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: Code: eb 8d cc cc cc 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5 e8 1a b5 38 ff 66 90 f7 c6 00 02 00 00 75 06 5d c3 cc cc cc cc fb 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 <5d> c3 cc cc cc cc 0f 1f 44 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5 8b 07
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb2ca0202b950 EFLAGS: 00010206
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: RAX: 0000000000000001 RBX: ffffa05c85ddc000 RCX: 0000000000000005
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: RDX: ffffa05c85ddc000 RSI: 0000000000000293 RDI: ffffa05c809ad180
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: RBP: ffffb2ca0202b950 R08: 0000000000000001 R09: ffffa05c8fbc4660
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: R10: 0000000000000005 R11: fffffffffffffff0 R12: 0000000000000000
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: R13: 0000000000000293 R14: ffffa05c80911000 R15: ffffa05c85048000
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  ata_scsi_queuecmd+0x6c/0xa0
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  scsi_dispatch_cmd+0x93/0x200
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  scsi_queue_rq+0x2d5/0x690
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  blk_mq_dispatch_rq_list+0x123/0x610
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  __blk_mq_sched_dispatch_requests+0xbf/0x150
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  blk_mq_sched_dispatch_requests+0x35/0x70
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  __blk_mq_run_hw_queue+0x34/0xc0
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  __blk_mq_delay_run_hw_queue+0x16a/0x170
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  blk_mq_run_hw_queue+0x87/0x130
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  blk_mq_sched_insert_request+0xa5/0x110
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  blk_execute_rq_nowait+0x5a/0x80
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  blk_execute_rq+0x55/0x110
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  sg_io+0x1bf/0x480
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  ? get_sg_io_hdr+0xdd/0xf0
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  ? path_openat+0xc4/0x2b0
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  scsi_ioctl+0x36d/0x4f0
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  sd_ioctl+0x11f/0x1d0
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  blkdev_ioctl+0x12f/0x270
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  ? __fget_files+0x86/0xc0
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  block_ioctl+0x46/0x60
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  __x64_sys_ioctl+0x92/0xd0
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  do_syscall_64+0x59/0xc0
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  ? do_user_addr_fault+0x1e7/0x670
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x37/0xb0
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  ? irqentry_exit_to_user_mode+0x9/0x20
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  ? irqentry_exit+0x1d/0x30
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  ? exc_page_fault+0x89/0x170
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x61/0xcb
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7ff4ee33caff
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: Code: 00 48 89 44 24 18 31 c0 48 8d 44 24 60 c7 04 24 10 00 00 00 48 89 44 24 08 48 8d 44 24 20 48 89 44 24 10 b8 10 00 00 00 0f 05 <41> 89 c0 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 1f 48 8b 44 24 18 64 48 2b 04 25 28 00
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffd95737e10 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007ffd95738020 RCX: 00007ff4ee33caff
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: RDX: 00007ffd95737e80 RSI: 0000000000002285 RDI: 0000000000000010
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: RBP: 0000000000001388 R08: 00000000ffffffff R09: 00007ff4ed888120
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000000
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel: R13: 00007ffd95738000 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000010
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm kernel:  </TASK>
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm rtkit-daemon[1310]: The canary thread is apparently starving. Taking action.
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm dockerd[1194]: time="2022-10-18T10:56:17.241286414+02:00" level=error msg="stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo"
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm dockerd[1194]: time="2022-10-18T10:56:17.241522199+02:00" level=error msg="stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo"
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm rtkit-daemon[1310]: Demoting known real-time threads.
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm rtkit-daemon[1310]: Successfully demoted thread 1353 of process 1308.
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm rtkit-daemon[1310]: Successfully demoted thread 1308 of process 1308.
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm rtkit-daemon[1310]: Successfully demoted thread 1317 of process 1307.
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm rtkit-daemon[1310]: Successfully demoted thread 1339 of process 1302.
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm rtkit-daemon[1310]: Successfully demoted thread 1302 of process 1302.
Oct 18 10:56:17 ubuntu-vm rtkit-daemon[1310]: Demoted 5 threads.
```

Any idea how I can troubleshoot what's the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. The error messages you're receiving point to a lack of memory for the VM. Be sure to give Ubuntu enough resources for the task you're asking it to do. 4GB is the minimum recommended for Ubuntu Desktop, but 8GB or more is ideal if you're doing anything with applications that use lots of files or computational processing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply matigo. I give 16GB to my vm and this problem is happening even when no app is running in Ubuntu. :(


user@ubuntu-vm:~$ free -h

               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available

Mem:            15Gi       1.0Gi        12Gi        38Mi       1.7Gi        14Gi

Swap:          2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi

Comment: You might need to get a clean kernel installed.  The `Tainted: G           OE     5.15.0-50-generic #56-Ubuntu` that you are seeing is `proprietary module was loaded`, `externally-built (“out-of-tree”) module was loaded` and `unsigned module was loaded`.  I am not sure how you installed your system but it sounds like kernel modules in there might be causing your troubles.  See:  https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/tainted-kernels.html

Comment: @Terrance I think it is tainted due to Virtualbox. I am not using any particular device which requires proprietary modules to be loaded. 
Do you know a way to identify why is tainted?

Comment: I have also installed a clean ubuntu 22.04 and it also shows as tainted, so pretty sure is Virtualbox (I have installed guest-additions).

Comment: You honestly could be looking at a VirtualBox issue and not an Ubuntu issue.  Have you by chance tried to create any other VMs even with different OSes with the exact same configuration that you have tried with Ubuntu to see if it is a VirtualBox issue and not an Ubuntu issue?

Comment: @Terrance Thank you for your reply. Even I suspect it is a virtualbox issue, but hard to identify what's wrong since I can't do a lot on the Host OS due to restricted company policy. If I find the culprit and possibly a workaround I will post it as answer.